# Modifying label on android spinner control

Tags: android

I have an android application with a spinner control that is backed by a database using a SimpleCursorAdapter.  I'd like to have a "custom" label on the selected item that will display two text fields from the database.  For example if there was set of records selected from the db that were something like a city state combination:

Las Vegas, Nevada 
Las Vegas, New Mexico

The drop down would only show two "Las Vegas" records. Is there a way to have the spinner show "Las Vegas - Nevada" and "Las Vegas - New Mexico". I am not sure I can bind more than one text field to the actual text that displays or if I have to concatenate the values or what exactly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to have the spinner show "Las Vegas - Nevada" and "Las Vegas - New Mexico". I am not sure I can bind more than one text field to the actual text that displays or if I have to concatenate the values or what exactly.

You can bind as many "text fields" as you want. You supply the IDs of the `TextView` widgets, and the corresponding column names from the `Cursor`, in the `SimpleCursorAdapter` constructor.